# Using different functions in summation

Tags: functions, summation

I am trying to evaluate the sum
$$c(k_1,k_2) = \sum_{a,b}{\Phi^{(2)}_{a,b} w_a(k_1) w_b(k_2)},$$
where $\Phi_{a,b}^{(2)}$ is the second derivative of $\Phi$ with respect to $a$ and $b$ respectively, and $w_\gamma(k)$ are different weight functions, e.g.: $w_1 = \cos(k)$, $w_2 = \sin(k)$, ... How can I define the weight functions in such a way that they can be used in the summation? Thanks!

Comment: sorry, I am not following you. In Latex you write $w_a(k_1)$ which means $w$ depends on both $a,k$ then you say as an example $w_1=\cos(k)$. So how many weight functions do you have? And what is $\gamma$ there? You write in Latex $w_a$ and $w_b$ then write $w_\gamma$. This is all not clear to me. Is there different weight function per each sum iteration? So the weight function depends on what exactly? i.e. what is the $i=1,2,3,\dots$ in $w_i(k)$ supposed to mean?

Comment: Sorry, I understand the confusion. $w(k)$ does not depend on a. There are four different weight functions $w_0(k)=\cos(k)$, $w_1(k)=\sin(k)$, $w_2(k)=\cos^2(k)$, $w_3(k)=\sin^2(k)$, which I have chosen arbitrarily here. The summation is over $a$ and $b$, where $a$ and $b$ are both running from 0 to 3. The first element of the summation would therefore be $\Phi^{(2)}_{(0,0)} w_0(k=k_1) w_0(k=k_2) = \Phi^{(2)}_{(0,0)} \cos(k_1) \cos(k_2)$.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are trying to do. Hopefully someone else would. good luck.